# Using UIImagePickerController in each tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to build a recipe app with a recipe upload function. In the PostController, there will be a **tableview** of all the cooking steps, each in a tableview cell. in the cell there will be a **textfield** of description and a **UIImageView** for picture upload ( the picture chosen from pickerController will be displayed in this UIImageView for later upload). I'm trying to do
`imageViewInCell.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleImageUpload)))` 
to call the`handleImageUpload()` function that generates a UIImagePickerController. But by doing this, I met two problems.

1. I cannot get the `index.row` value of the cell by the selector in `UITapGestureRecognizer` , with out the index I cannot assign the chosen image back to the UIImageView of the cell.
2. Even if I got index.row in handleImageUpload, I still need the function below to assign selected image. How would this function accept my parameter and find the corresponding imageViewInCell?

   ```
   func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
       if let selectedImage: UIImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            imageViewInCell.image = selectedImage
       }
       dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
   ```

Comment: Why are using a tap gesture instead of didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: I added UITapGesture for the imageView because this operation is simply only related to the picture. Using didSelectRowAtIndexPath may not be the choice because there's a textfield in the cell as well.

Comment: Finally I saved the index with both the global variable `selectedIndex`(used by `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`) and the  `cell.imageViewInCell.tag` (used by `handleImageUpload()`), every time  `handleImageUpload()` is called, it assign `selectedIndex` with value `cell.imageViewInCell.tag`. In `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` it takes the global variable to find the corresponding cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the indexPath.row as the tag of your imageview in cellForRowAtIndexPath like Below

```
cell.yourImageView.tag = indexPath.row
```

and then you can get this indepath backagain using below

```
  let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.tag, inSection: 0)
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! yourcellClass!
cell.yourImgeView.image = selectedImage
```

Comment: This idea helps. The problem has been solved now, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want `thehandleImageUpload()` to be called only on tap on `imageView` instead of whole cell, hence you're using *tapGesture*.

Now to answer your question, assign tag to your imageView like this :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
//cell configuration
cell.imageView.tag = indexPath.row
return cell
}
```

And you can assign selected image to selected cell like this:

Now your `handleImageUpload()` is:

```
func handleImageUpload(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
selectedIndexPath = sender.tag
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let selectedImage: UIImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(selectedIndexPath) as UITableViewCell
            cell.imageViewInCell.image = selectedImage
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: With gesture method you can only pass GestureRecognizer object not any thing other.

Comment: Edited answer .

Comment: It helps, but a similar thought was answered earlier, so I accept that one. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty late to the party, but the code below should work.

I'd have the UITableViewCell do the work of dealing with the image. Make it a UIPickerControllerDelegate and have it hold onto a closure to present the picker when necessary (as it can't present something itself as it is not a view controller).

Something like:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let photoCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PhotosTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! PhotosTableViewCell
    photoCell.takePicture = {[weak self] in
                let imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
                imagePicker.delegate = photoCell
                imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
                self?.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
```

Have your UITableviewCell implement:

```
var takePicture: (() -> Void)?
```

to hold the closure. Then call it from a button or something to make it trigger.
Use:

```
 func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
```

to deal with the image.